# using express-device with sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

been trying to play with sails framework as planning to port my express app.
The problem I got into was how to make express-device npm package to work with it. In express app I just require module like in this case var device = require('express-device') and then configure it in server.configure. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the solution... After running npm install express-device --save I had to create a express.js module inside of config/ dir and the content of module looks like this:

```
module.exports.express = {
  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    var device = require('express-device');
    app.use(device.capture());
  }
};
```

so now in each controller I can find the type of device that request is coming from if I need to:

```
index: function(req, res) {
  device = req.device.type;
  if(device == 'mobile') {
    // do something different ;)
  }
}
```

Maybe there's some more clever ways to  do this but this works fine for me :)

Comment: Is this working? This might be the best approach and this should also be the answer. I am also looking for snippets or modules that might get current device of the client using Sails then I cam across express-device which is directly applied with ExpressJS .

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit of looking at the Sails middleware documentation (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware) to figure this out, but it ends up being a little easier than the previous answer.

In `config/http.js`, you'll want to add the following bits of code:

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: [
      ...
      'expressDevice',
      ...
    ],

    expressDevice: require('express-device').capture(),
  }
}
```

This will get the same result as the previous answer of having `req.device` available on every request.