# SailsJS : How to get all current installed module versions in a Project

Tags: node.js, express, npm, sails.js

I would like to ask how to determine the Express version that is being used of the SailsJS. I know that Sails JS is built on top of Express.

I am using the version below:

`"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~0.8.4",
    .
    .
    .
    "rc": "~0.5.0",
    "sails": "~0.11.2",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.0"
  }`

I am asking this because I want to install this module https://github.com/rguerreiro/express-device and use with sailsJS.

In this particular module, the version is dependent on the Express version that is why I need the Express ver in order to install the appropriate express-device version.

I have seen also how to use it with sails in this post: [using express-device with sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436169/using-express-device-with-sails)

The thing is it was 2 years ago and Express had fewer version and the latest can be installed.

Cheers!

Comment: SailsJS is using `"express": "3.20.2"` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/package.json).

Comment: There you go, I was looking at node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/package.json too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output npm dependency tree with

```
npm ls --depth=1
```

Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Comment: This is the correct answer since it will output the version installed in the current instance via command. I had to go to my sails project root directory and run `npm ls --depth=1`